# polygon button with clickable area plygon

Tags: android, button

[an irregular polygon.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdnCK.png)

As android follows box model it's hard to create irregular buttons but i want a button like this which will be clickable only within the visible area any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:clickable="true"
android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world"
android:onClick="clickTest"
android:src="@drawable/sample_img" />
```

put your polygon image inside imageview in "android: src" field. Then you will get clickTest method inside your activity as shown below

```
public class MainActvity extends Activity
{

public void clickTest(View view)
   {

   }
}
```

Comment: this doesn't works it's still clickable in outside polygon area

Comment: make sure that image that you put inside your src field does not have blank space around it in its png or jpeg file

Answer (score 0):

The views are always rectangle. You need to track the event in [onTouch](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html#onTouch(android.view.View,%20android.view.MotionEvent)) method and check if the event is within your drawing bounds or not so that you can trigger `onClick` accordingly.

A good approach is mentioned in this [blog](http://fancifulandroid.blogspot.com/2013/01/make-imageviews-transparent-area-not.html). I'm not sure this will work or not because I have not tested this but you need to do something like this in `onTouch` of your view.

Comment: i guess this does the part but i'll test it throughly. Thanks